# Neo4j indexing with Lucene and query with SOLR

Tags: plugins, indexing, lucene, solr, neo4j

I am using Neo4j with Lucene indexing, which works pretty good with nodes, maybe not so well with relationships. But My question is: is there a way to use SOLR to query on Neo4j since it uses Lucene? is there a plugin somewhere or do I have to create my own?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be released yet, but see http://lists.neo4j.org/pipermail/user/2010-January/002372.html

Answer (score 2):

What is the problem with index for relationships? Have you looked at the integrated index framework, http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Index_Framework#Relationship_indexes ?

Regarding you question I haven't looked into Solr much.

/ Mattias, main contributor to lucene integration for Neo4j.